# Does the linear independence of given countable set can be deduced by that of its finite subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra

In p.43 example 16 of Hoffman/Kunze's Linear Algebra(2nd Edition), there's the following argument:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomial functions over the complex
>    numbers and let $f_k(x)=x^k$ and we want to show $B=\{f_0, f_1,
>  f_2, \cdots \}$ is the basis for $V$. Clearly $B$ spans $V$, so it
>    remains to show $B$ is linearly independent.

And here comes the part where I got confused:

> To show this, it is enough to show that each finite subset of $B$ is linearly independent.

What I want to ask you is :

1. Does this hold by the fact that the set whose cardinality is strictly less than $\aleph_0$ is only finite set?
2. If so, what if the vector space $V$ had uncountable dimension? To show the subset $S$ of $V$ is linearly independent, is it enough to show the proper subsets of $S$ are linearly indepent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $S \subseteq V$ is linearly independent by definition if given any **finite** subset $F \subseteq S$, the only solution of the equation $\sum_{v \in F} a_v \cdot v = 0$ is $a_v = 0$ for all $v \in F$. In particular, this implies that a subset $S \subseteq V$ is linearly independent if and only if any finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent, irregardless of the cardinality of the dimension of $V$.

Comment: Thanks! I just understood the finiteness was given by Definition..

Answer (score 1):

as you probably know, the first three together (size) of units of
measurement are: infinite set uncountable, countable infinite and
finite.

by definition: a  vectors set $A$ of  $V$ is a free system if and
only if each finite subset $S$ of $A$ is free ( Independent of the
nature of A countable or not).

when $A$ is countable, to  show that $A$ is free, it is specified
in sub set $S$, whose cardinal $n$, that way, when $n$ runs $N$,
all finite subsets of $A$ will be taken.